# Paypal lanza error pero no especifica en que

Tags: paypal

primero que todo implenté un sistema de pagos online usando Payum en mi aplicacion  de symfony, lo probé usando usuarios del sandbox(prueba) y funciona correctamente, pero cuando cambio a los usuarios reales paypal lanza este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pudiera saber porque ocurre este error. Cualquier información adicional puedo ponerla, llevo buen tiempo con este problema y no encuentro solución.

Comment: Amigo ya intentaste llamar a Paypal? Saludos

Comment: Debes tener un archivo de logs ahi viene la info del error.

Comment: donde estaría ese log??